# String accessing from c++ to python

Tags: c++, string, python-3.x, communication, ctypes

I am trying to access a string returned by C++ code from the python code.
C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo{
    public:
        char* bar(){
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
            return "abc";
        }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    char* Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ char* x = foo->bar(); return x;}
}
```

Then I created the library libfoo.so for this c++ code.

Now in python I am using the below code to access the string :

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        return lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)

f = Foo()
x = f.bar()
a = c_char_p(x)
print(a.value)
```

The output I am getting is: **b'abc'** instead of **abc**

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If this is a 64-bit process, you're lucky it didn't segfault. You're implicitly casting the object pointer to a 32-bit int. You need to set `lib.Foo_new.restype = c_void_p`, `lib.Foo_bar.restype = c_char_p`, and `lib.Foo_bar.argtypes  = (c_void_p,)`.

Comment: As to the `bytes` result, a `char *` is a byte string. Decode the result as a unicode string, e.g. `return lib.Foo_bar(self.obj).decode('utf-8')`. Then `f = Foo(); a = f.bar(); print(a)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Will update the code accordingly.